# Powershell to call .bat file with arguments in a list

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, jobs

I want to call a batch file from PowerShell script with parameters in a list
For example
List contain[PARAM1,PARAM2,PARAM3]
first iteration should run
cmd.exe /C process.bat  $PARAM1
second iteration should run
cmd.exe /C process.bat  $PARAM2
and so on

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your list to `ForEach-Object` and call `cmd` from there:

```
$list = 'ParamArg1', 'ParamArg2', 'ParamArg3'

$list |ForEach-Object {
  cmd /c process.bat $_
}
```